# How do I truncate a string of text to a number of characters ending with ellipsis for an array of paragraph tags using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach, truncate, selectors-api

My example I've tried, gives me [object NodeList].
So what I'm trying to do, is truncate paragraphs of text, so that I can add a show more button to display the rest of the text.

```
  var testimonialFeedback = document.querySelectorAll('.expanded-text'); 

  var testimonialArray = [...testimonialFeedback];

  
  function ellipsify () {
          if (testimonialFeedback.length > 100) {
              return (testimonialFeedback.substring(0, 100) + "...");
          }
          else {
          return testimonialFeedback;
      }
  }

  testimonialArray.forEach(e => {
    e.textContent = ellipsify(testimonialFeedback.textContent);
  });
```

Comment: insert tag with text

Comment: you're passing an argument to `ellipsify` but the function doesn't use it at all, it just refers to `testimonialFeedback` directly

Comment: also `querySelectorAll` returns multiple elements, so which element do you expect `testimonialFeedback.textContent` to return the content of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten the function param..

```js
const testimonialFeedback = document.querySelectorAll('.expanded-text'); 
const testimonialArray = [...testimonialFeedback];
const testimonialFeedbackMaxLength = 100;

function ellipsify (testimonialFeedback) {
  if (testimonialFeedback.length > testimonialFeedbackMaxLength) {
      testimonialFeedback = testimonialFeedback.substring(0, testimonialFeedbackMaxLength) + "...";
  }
  return testimonialFeedback;
}

testimonialArray.forEach(e => {
  e.textContent = ellipsify(e.textContent);
});
```

```css
.expanded-text {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="expanded-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="expanded-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="expanded-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

P.S. it is easier to do with text-overflow css.

```css
.expanded-text {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="expanded-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="expanded-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="expanded-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

Comment: Goodness, I swear i added that before while playing around with the code, and it didn't work. It could probably have been the return.
Thank you so much for the help

Comment: P.S I have tried the CSS method before. My paragraph tags are within div cards, so the text is wrapping. So that didn't quite work, it made each of my card divs full length which i didn't want. 
Thank you again @Arthur Rubens

Comment: I have cleaned a code a little bit, the length(100) must be const..

Comment: Noted. Much appreciated :)